# Getting the size of member variable

Tags: c++, c++11

If there is a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) structure, with some member variables, for example like this:

```
struct foo
{
   short a;
   int b;
   char c[50];
   // ...
};
```

Is there a way to get the size of a member variable in bytes, without creating an object of this type?

I know that this will work:

```
foo fooObj;
std::cout << sizeof( fooObj.a ) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof( fooObj.b ) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof( fooObj.c ) << std::endl;
```

Would the following be optimized by the compiler and prevent the construction of an object?

```
std::cout << sizeof( foo().a ) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Unless they are static, I don't think so...

Comment: What's the exact requirement? Why can't you use the compile-time information? In my understanding, C++ doesn't dynamic class generation and manipulation

Answer (score 27, accepted):

5.3.3/1:

> The sizeof operator yields the number
>   of bytes in the object representation
>   of its operand. The operand is either
>   an expression, **which is not evaluated**,
>   or a parenthesized type-id.

The above means the following construct is well defined:

```
sizeof( ((foo *) 0)->a);
```

Comment: @Martin: But he writes a macro, you would say *"Way too much work and it hides the actual meaning."* :P

Comment: @Nawaz: As I don't have an answer I can have it both ways (its like having cake and eating it). Here my job is to point out the obvious :-) You can really argue against either point they are both true. The job for the OP is to decide a) Upgrade the compiler to C++0x (as pointed out below) or decide between the lesser of two evils (once all the relevant points about both evils have been highlighted).

Comment: @Nawaz: But based on the standard above. The OP's original comments holds, `sizeof(foo().a)` is valid, well defined, the object is not constructed, is not ugly and does not require the extra work of a potentially misleading macro.

Comment: @Martin: It is however dependent on `foo` being constructible.

Comment: @Erik: True and definitely worth pointing out. But the OP did explicitly mention that the struct was POD and thus it will always be constructable.

Comment: @Martin: What? `foo()` doesn't construct object, even be it anonymous object?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, not in this case, the operand to sizeof isn't evaluated.

Comment: @Erik: Awesome. How come I missed that.

Answer (score 44):

You can do that in C++0x:

```
sizeof(foo::a);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the obvious:

```
sizeof( foo::a )
```

In C++, sizeof is ALWAYS evaluated at compile time, so there is no runtime cost whatsoever.

Comment: This works :)
it just references the member inside the class definition.

Comment: @Nawaz Eh? What has static got to do with it?

Comment: @unapersson: You're accessing `a` which is non-static member of `foo`.

Comment: I should point out that I switched to compiling my code with c++0x some time ago. Maybe we need two C++ tags here?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y But the sizeof( foo::a ) doesn't work for the current version of c++. It works for c++0x

Comment: @VJo: I know. I was just replying to @unapersson's comment that we might need two C++-tags. If the OP is interested in C++0x solutions, he should just add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Why -2? The answer is correct, and I was thinking to accept it

Comment: @VJo It is C++0x, not current standard code. I should have made that clear, but I tend to forget the old stuff.

Answer (score 11):

Use this form: `sizeof(foo::a)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

C++-0x allows you to do this:

```
  std::cout << sizeof( foo::a ) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof( foo::b ) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof( foo::c ) << std::endl;
```

C++-0x allows sizeof to work on members of classes without an explicit object.

The paper is here: [Extending sizeof to apply to non-static data members without an object (revision 1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html)

I saw the post about this above too late.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create macro wrapper of what @Erik suggested as:

```
#define SIZE_OF_MEMBER(cls, member) sizeof( ((cls*)0)->member )
```

And then use it as:

```
cout << SIZE_OF_MEMBER(foo, c) << endl;
```

Output:

```
50
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/ZRiMe

Comment: Way too much work and it hides the actual meaning. At least give the macro a name that explains what it is doing.

Comment: @Martin: I didn't find any compelling name for the macro. Suggest me one. :-)

Comment: SIZE_OF_MEMBER, That's what she said.

Comment: Still way to much work. But at least the name stands out now.

Comment: use: sizeof(foo().a) or sizeof(foo::a)

Comment: @Martin: That I immediately understood when @Erik reminded me that `foo()` in `sizeof` isn't evaluated. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
struct foo
{
   short a;
   int b;
   char c[50];
   // ...
   static const size_t size_a = sizeof(a);
   static const size_t size_b = sizeof(b);
   static const size_t size_c = sizeof(c);
};
```

Usage:

```
foo::size_a
```

Comment: This would work, but would be PITA, because that would require adding 10 additional static variables

Comment: `sizeof` does not yield `int`, it yields `std::size_t`.

Comment: @iammilind : I was not the downvoter, unfortunately. ;-]