# Template specialization to check whether a member is present

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This is a follow up to my question [SFINAE with variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636275/sfinae-with-variadic-templates). I was trying to construct a variadic template named `has_member` for checking whether a class has a member (called `member`).

I tried to see if I could use `size_t` instead of `void` in the answer to that question and not use variadic templates, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ClassWithMember
{
    public:
    int member;
};
class ClassWithoutMember
{
};

template <typename T,typename=size_t>
class has_member: public std::false_type
{
};
template <typename T>
class has_member<T,decltype(sizeof(typename T::member))>: public std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T1,
          std::enable_if_t<has_member<T1>::value>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T1& obj) { cout<<"Function for classes with member"<<endl; }

template <typename T1,
          std::enable_if_t<!has_member<T1>::value>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T1& obj) { cout<<"Function for classes without member"<<endl; }


int main()
{
    ClassWithMember objWithMember;
    ClassWithoutMember objWithoutMember;
    my_function (objWithMember);
    my_function (objWithoutMember);
}
```

I get no errors, but the specialization is never used. Only the function for classes without the member gets called. Could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typename before `T::member` is needless.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ClassWithMember
{
    public:
    int member;
};
class ClassWithoutMember
{
};

template <typename T,typename=size_t>
class has_member: public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
class has_member<T,decltype(sizeof(T::member))>: public std::true_type
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
{
};

template <typename T1,
          std::enable_if_t<has_member<T1>::value>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T1& obj) { cout<<"Function for classes with member"<<endl; }

template <typename T1,
          std::enable_if_t<!has_member<T1>::value>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T1& obj) { cout<<"Function for classes without member"<<endl; }


int main()
{
    ClassWithMember objWithMember;
    ClassWithoutMember objWithoutMember;
    my_function (objWithMember);
    my_function (objWithoutMember);
}
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18d88d4ed82d2407)**

[OT] Just a tip for further metaprogramming: you can also test by using the real types instead of templates.

Comment: It worked! Could you please add a short explanation maybe?

Comment: It looks like there is no problem with real types. It was introduced in c++0x apparently.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976879/getting-the-size-of-member-variable
So why is there a problem with templates? I treid out what Denis mentioned at the end of his answer, and there were no errors at all.

Comment: Corrected it, the `typename` keyword wasn't neccessary.

Comment: It's not a dependent type i think: `error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'member' in 'ClassWithMember'`

Comment: Hmm.. yeah. I don't see the error you mention, but member is not really a type. That explains it..